# How can I open a new tab in terminal in Mac

Tags: mac, terminal

When I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open an new tab in terminal, it always open my home directory.

How can I new a tab which open the same directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal will do this by default if you're using bash as your shell (which is the default).

You can set preferences to decide whether to have new tabs and/or windows open at the same directory as the current terminal:

> Terminal > Preferences > Startup > New windows/tabs open with > Same Working Directory

This works by having your shell (or other programs) send an escape sequence to tell Terminal the current working directory. The code to do this is in the system-wide bash configuration file /etc/bashrc.

If you're using zsh, I've adapted and expanded the code for /etc/zshrc in my answer to [Resume Zsh-Terminal (OS X Lion)](https://superuser.com/questions/313650/resume-zsh-terminal-os-x-lion/328148#328148).

Answer (score 23):

command + t

(for tab)

Typing in more to satisfy Stackoverflow's requirement that Body is at least 30 characters.

Comment: ... and "command + w" to close the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps as shown here : [Open a new tab on Terminal with the same path](http://elsethenif.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/open-a-new-tab-on-terminal-with-the-same-path-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [iTerm 2](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/) and learn more about [customizing it](http://xanana.ucsc.edu/xtal/iterm_tab_customization.html) to your needs

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like iTerm has a future, the most recent 0.x version will be two years old in september. http://iterm2.com perhaps?

Comment: true, the screenshot is for iTerm2 :)

Comment: @DanielBeck Funny seeing as iterm is still around now and gaining in popularity

Comment: @Mosselman Do you have a reference? It doesn't seem anything has changed: "iTerm project is currently on hold (See the goodbye note from Fabian). We recommend you to check out iTerm 2, a new project that is based on iTerm and has many new features and enhancements." per http://iterm.sourceforge.net/ Also "iTerm2 is a more up to date fork as the original project is not maintained." from https://launchpad.net/iterm

Answer (score 1):

On MAC 10

```
Terminal > Preferences > General>
```

change follow attributes to

```
New windows open with > Same Working Directory
New tabs open with > Same Working Directory
```

To apply change press `command + T`