# Resume Zsh-Terminal (OS X Lion)

Tags: terminal.app, zsh, osx-lion

OS X Lion has "Resume" feature, i. e. when you reopen an app it restores all windows and their contents. That works for Terminal as well. But if you use Zsh instead of Bash it doesn't restore opened directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related to the answers below: making terminal.app aware of the directory is also useful for opening new terminals in the same directory as the current one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This isn't entirely correct, for reasons mentioned in the comments. [Use the answer below](https://superuser.com/questions/313650/resume-zsh-terminal-os-x-lion/315029#answer-328148). Thanks @ChrisPage for going the extra mile :)

The answer can be found by reverse engineering how bash does it in `/etc/bashrc`. I tried many approaches from around the net but Apple's way seems to work best (go figure).

In your `.zshrc` add the following

```
# Set Apple Terminal.app resume directory
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "Apple_Terminal" ]] && [[ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]] {
  function chpwd {
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
  }

  chpwd
}
```

Happy resuming.

> For clarify, this answer pertains to the mysterious message in OS X Lion's Terminal.app preferences:
>
> **Programs notify Terminal of the current working directory using
>   escape sequences. You may need to configure your shell or other
>   programs to enable this behavior.*
>
> This answer works when you're using zsh as your shell. Terminal Resume for bash has already been implemented by Apple.

Comment: Probably not a big thing in practice, but I see the stock /etc/bashrc has the last line of `chpwd` as `printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"` with the double quotes. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is now making its way into oh-my-zsh (see https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/522). You'll need to make sure you've turned on the osx plugin in your zshrc.

Comment: Also note that this code only percent-encodes spaces. For bonus points, make it percent-encode all illegal URL characters (and see if you can do it without invoking any programs). This is important if you want it to work with all valid pathnames. Also, some characters aren't even considered part of escape sequences, so percent-encoding is required to get them to the terminal. I was able to do this for bash, but I haven't tried testing it with zsh.

Comment: The quotes around "$PWD_URL" are required to prevent the pathname from being munged. EDIT: This is required in bash, but optional in zsh. I prefer to use the quotes consistently so it's portable.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, Chris. I've updated the script to use the double quotes for consistency.

Comment: Chris, yes this only escapes spaces -- I figured if Apple's built-in bash version only requires the spaces escaped then Terminal.app would handle this behaviour from here too. What sorts of paths are breaking? I'm able to make weird paths like "~/©/stΩff" work with the default behaviour.

Comment: @CaptainPete Please use the complete version I posted. Terminal cannot “handle this behavior” if invalid characters are not percent-encoded. First, to conform to terminal standards, it doesn’t treat control characters and some whitespace as part of an escape sequence. Second, to conform to URL standards, it requires all invalid URL characters to be percent-encoded.

Comment: The reason this escape sequence was created, and the reason it uses URLs, was to provide complete support for all valid pathnames, not just some of them, via URL percent-encoding. The current version of /etc/bashrc should only be taken as a starting point to draw from, not a justification for limiting the solution when you’re going out of your way to develop and install code for another shell.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPage, nice solution! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 28):

Here's my adaptation of /etc/bashrc for zsh. I've included percent-encoding of all URL characters that require it, which is important if you want this to work with all valid file and directory names.

This registers a `precmd` hook, which allows more than one function to be registered in other scripts and configuration files.

UPDATED March 2019: Set `LC_ALL` to empty so it doesn’t override `LC_CTYPE`. Use `precmd` to update the working directory at each prompt instead of using `chpwd` to update it every time it is changed—command pipelines may change it temporarily and the terminal shouldn’t display those. Also, it can be helpful to have each prompt update the terminal state in case it was changed during the previous command. Use `printf -v` to explicitly write to the variable instead of using subshell syntax.

```sh
# Tell the terminal about the working directory whenever it changes.

if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ]] && [[ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]]; then

    update_terminal_cwd() {
        # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL, including
        # the host name to disambiguate local vs. remote paths.

        # Percent-encode the pathname.
        local url_path=''
        {
            # Use LC_CTYPE=C to process text byte-by-byte. Ensure that
            # LC_ALL isn't set, so it doesn't interfere.
            local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
            for ((i = 1; i <= ${#PWD}; ++i)); do
                ch="$PWD[i]"
                if [[ "$ch" =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]; then
                    url_path+="$ch"
                else
                    printf -v hexch "%02X" "'$ch"
                    url_path+="%$hexch"
                fi
            done
        }

        printf '\e]7;%s\a' "file://$HOST$url_path"
    }

    # Register the function so it is called at each prompt.
    autoload add-zsh-hook
    add-zsh-hook precmd update_terminal_cwd
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, the accepted solution didn't work for me, but this one does.

Comment: This one is working for me as well.

Comment: It should also be noted that this solution is already in [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), just activate the `terminalapp` plugin.

Comment: Just to be clear, @Simon means this is *now* in oh-my-zsh, added since this answer was written.

Comment: That is correct @ChrisPage, I apologize for the ambiguous phrasing (english is not my mother tongue). What I meant to say was just that, you don't need to paste this in your `.zprofile` or whatever, like I did before realizing it is in fact available in `oh-my-zsh`. It is in deed the exact same solution and you deserve all the credit.

Comment: Thanks ChrisPage and Simon, it's been bugging me for ages. @ChrisPage, do you think it would be worth updating the answer to indicate that this is not part of the plugin so it's more clearly visible

Comment: @IlyaKatz I’m not sure what you’re trying to say. Is “not” a typo for “now”?

Comment: @ChrisPage, sorry, you're correct.

Comment: @IlyaKatz I’m unfamiliar with oh-my-zsh. Can someone suggest how to describe exactly how it’s part of oh-my-zsh, and how to describe it to both people familiar and unfamiliar with it? And how to link to it?

Comment: This is working for me, except that dir names with multibyte UTF-8 characters in them (for example, "ԱԲԳ") get garbled. I think you need `LC_CTYPE=C` instead of `LANG=C`. When I tested it, LC_CTYPE affected the behavior of `$#` and `$x[n]`, but LANG did not.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I assume that’s because your environment has set LC_CTYPE, which overrides LANG. I’ll see about updating this to use LC_CTYPE instead.

Comment: Ah, yep: I have LC_CTYPE set. oh-my-zsh sets it from LANG during its initialization. Didn't realize that was nonstandard.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I have tested and updated the code to use LC_CTYPE instead of LANG.

Comment: @ChrisPage: Thanks for this. I installed oh-my-zsh to get this feature, but have uninstalled it because it did too much nonsense. Your answer works great. Anyway, for those who have installed oh-my-zsh, they can put `plugins=(terminalapp)` (or a list, like `plugins=(git osx terminalapp)` say) in their `~/.zshrc` to get [exactly the contents of your answer](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/terminalapp/terminalapp.plugin.zsh) loaded for them.

Comment: **Update:** OMZ has since added this to the auto-loaded `lib/termsupport.zsh` file, which [as of right now](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/d7797503418422148e84bc06c9e446bdd77c3a01/lib/termsupport.zsh#L82-L105) can be used *without* the rest of OMZ, as long as you also include `lib/functions.zsh`. (Incase any of the rest of you don't like copy-pasting chunks of code into `.zshrc`, and would prefer to depend upon external resources!)

Comment: … for any of you using Zgen, this [becomes as easy as](http://superuser.com/a/1031708/22030): `zgen load robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh lib/functions.zsh && zgen load robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh lib/termsupport.zsh`

Comment: Interestingly, this code is used verbatim by Apple in /etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal now that Zsh is the default shell.